# Notepad++ has problems with text autocompletion under Wine

Tags: wine, text-editor

I just installed Notepad++ under Wine and I noticed a massive problem.  When I type, the autocomplete box appears correctly but it covers up the text that I am typing.  This gets annoying because I want to see what I am typing.

[image]

I know there are other text editors for Ubuntu but I would like to stay with Notepad++ if I can because I have been using Notepad++ for a long time under Windows.  I have tried other text editors, and they all had problems that caused me to have more frustration.

Could someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You could disable the autocompletion feature by each character input and open up the autocompletion popup by shortcut

Answer (score 5):

I did a bit more digging and found out a solution.
I had to go into the wine configuration, `winecfg`, and disable *Allow the windows manager to control the windows*, located under the *Graphics* tab.
This fixed the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the code completion popup window, go to Settings->Preferences...->Auto-Completion and untick Enable auto-completion on each input.